# Changing the "how to ask" text to be more specific?

Tags: discussion

The "How to Ask" text seems a bit vague.  Since comments like:

- Can you describe what your algorithm is, not everybody knows the exact book you are using?
- What is your code supposed to be doing in words?

Are pretty common, maybe some kinds of specific direction would be useful.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but until they select moderators... nothing about any of that can be changed. Although I agree that moderators should do what you're saying... when they're able.

Comment: @Patrick87 The “how to ask” text can't be changed. Only the first part of the [FAQ] (“What kind of questions can I ask here?”) can be edited by moderators, the rest is the same on every site.

Comment: @Gilles, may I suggest posting your comment as an answer so the question becomes answered? :)

Comment: @Kaveh I meant this more as a note that if we want specific directions, we should think of putting them in the FAQ. And this could also be a feature request to customize the “How to Ask” text (which isn't unthinkable, it might happen if we aren't the only site with this request and we show a very strong case). I expect answers here to consist of things we'd want to put there.

Comment: @Gilles, good point.